# Error after including /usr/include/openssl to project. (Newbie)

Tags: c++, eclipse, openssl, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse (2020-06) and CDT on a Fedora desktop and am trying to learn C++.

In my code, the following lines are compiled without problems:

```
  rc = read(Socket_ID, &ts, BUFSIZ);
  if (rc == -1) {
    warnx("Reading timestamp failed");
    Socket_ID = -1;
  }
```

After adding /usr/include/openssl to the C/C++ build settings, I get this error

```
error: ‘warnx’ was not declared in this scope
```

At this moment I even haven't included openssl/md5.h

After removing the 'warnx'-line, the code compiles without error.

Does this mean that openssl can not be used in a CPP-project or does Eclipse need extra settings?

Ben

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't mean that, but you don't need to add `/usr/include/openssl` to your include settings because openssl is already mentioned in

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>
```

Only if you said

```
#include <md5.h>
```

would you need to have /usr/include/openssl added to your settings.

Seems to be quite a common misunderstanding that the 'library' directory has to be mentioned both in the include settings and in the `#include` directive, but it's not the case.

Comment: Now that I've looked it over more, I'm pretty sure that adding `/usr/include/openssl` to the list of include folders moved `openssl/err.h` up ahead of `err.h` when the preprocessor's looking for includes. So when the `#include<err.h>` needed to get the declaration of `warnx` is resolved, the preprocessor included `openssl/err.h` instead.